# Weird image attributes when using get_the_post_thumbnail(wordpress development)

Tags: wordpress, codex

```
<?php get_the_post_thumbnail(get_the_id(),array(370,552));?>
```

display the following image

Why is creating the attributes 1 and 0 by default ? any ideea ?

I have only defaults plugin installed

Comment: I posted the image but is not showing up, so here is again <img class="attachment-41 size-41 wp-post-image" width="370" height="562" 1="552" 0="370" alt="370x552" src="path to img">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the array from get_the_id(),array(370,552));  to 
get_the_id(),'my-custom-size');

Answer (score 0):

Be careful, it's [get_the_ID()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_id/) with uppercase.

Comment: php is not case sensitive(for functions), you can use get_the_ID or get_the_id